# Need help seeing if homogeneous substitution applies here

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

the following problem is this:
Find the General Solution of the $DE:xy'-y=y^3cos(19x)$

I know that Bernoulli Sub would work here, but I want to see if Homogeneous would work too.

My Work: Divide both sides by x

$y'- \frac yx = \frac yxy^2cos(19x)$

Then move $\frac yx$ over to the right side of the equation

$y' = \frac yx + \frac yxy^2cos(19x)$

Let's apply the homogeneous substitution

let $v = \frac yx$

then $y=vx$

and $y'=v+v'x$

Sub these values into the DE to get

$v+v'x=v+v\cdot v^2x^2cos(19x)$

subtract v from both sides

$v'x=v^3x^2cos(19x)$

Divide both sides by x

$v'=v^3xcos(19x)$

$\cfrac {dv}{dx} = v^3xcos(19x)$

Seperate and Solve

$\int\cfrac {dv}{v^3} = \int xcos(19x)dx$

$\cfrac {-1}{2v^2} = \cfrac {19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)}{361}+C$

Take Reciprocal

$-2v^2= \cfrac{361}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}$

Divide both sides by -2

$v^2= \cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}$

Take the square root of both sides

$v= \sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$,
$v = -\sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$

back sub y in
$\frac yx = \sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$,
$\frac yx = -\sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$

Solve for y

$y = x \cdot \sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$,
$y = x \cdot -\sqrt{\cfrac{-180.5}{19xsin(19x)+cos(19x)+C}}$

This is the final answer

Did I do this correctly? Is my reasoning fine?

Comment: Looks good to me.  You have $v=\pm \sqrt {\text {something}}$

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'-y=y^3\cos(19x)$$
$$\left(\dfrac yx  \right)'=\dfrac {y^3 \cos (19x)}{x^2}$$
$$\dfrac {x^3}{y^3}\left(\dfrac yx \right)'= {x \cos (19x)}$$
$$\left(\dfrac xy \right)^3d\left(\dfrac yx \right)= {x \cos (19x)}dx$$
So yes this part of your attempt is correct.
$$-\dfrac 12\left(\dfrac xy \right)^2= \dfrac x {19}\sin (19x) -\dfrac 1 {19}\int \sin (19x)dx$$
$$-\dfrac 12\left(\dfrac xy \right)^2= \dfrac x {19}\sin (19x) +\dfrac 1 {19^2} \cos (19x)dx+C$$

Comment: Oh so did I mess up somewhere, if so where?

Comment: Your answer looks good... You have that $v=\pm \sqrt {.......}$ You missing a negative solution @SleeperMan23

Comment: I did put a negative solution next to the y, it's x (times) - /sqrt (stuff)

Comment: I didn t talk about that...I am talking about the $v^2$ Adter that when you write $v=.....$ you should have two solutions @SleeperMan23

Comment: Yeah i put two square roots above, one v that has the positive square root and one v that has the negative square root to the right of it? Isn't that what I'm supposed to do/what you're referring to?

Comment: Ok I see now. And as I already said I see no mistakes in your solution Good job @SleeperMan23

Comment: It's more simple to write $y=\mp x \sqrt {....}$ @SleeperMan23

Comment: ah got ya, sorry I wanted to write it out like that but I just don't know the mathjax code, could you please tell me what it is for future reference?

Comment: For $\pm$ just write it as \pm  or \mp  between dollars @SleeperMan23